# Pseudo-classes aren't working in IE for jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am building an accordion that can expand on click for each and also has an expand all button. I've used `::before` on the accordion heads and on the expand all button. Everything appears fine in Chrome and Firefox but IE seems to be having an issue with showing the psuedo-classes and margins. Any help would be appreciated!!

http://jsfiddle.net/JheRh/

Comment: Which IE? and can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: Pseudo-code? Seriously?

Comment: @Huangism I've edited to just show the fiddle -- thanks for the request. And I'm using IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume you are using IE8 to test this.  If that is the case, IE8 only supports the single colon syntax for the `before` and `after` pseudo elements.

`::after -> :after`
`::before -> :before`

I do believe that most browsers support the single colon syntax as well, so it would be best to use that unless you can drop

### EDIT - Work around

After looking at the fiddler, for some reason (still looking at it), IE is putting your `li` elements into an empty tag.  This is causing issues with your selector.  You have `#nav > li > a` but in IE, it sees them as `#nav > emptyEl > li > a`.

The simplest way to fix it is to just make the selector not as specific, `#nav li a` will do what you want for now.

### Edit 2 - Solution

So, at least with the fiddler, you have malformed HTML.  I would really encourage you to go through the code and make sure every element has a start and end that it should.

To make it work in the fiddler, I just had to add a `<tr><td>` elements right before the `<ul id="nav">` element and `</td></tr>` right before the ending `</tbody>` element.

[Working Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/JheRh/5/)

Comment: I've tried both single and double with the same result. Thanks for the attempt though, Justin.

Comment: @user2836396 See my reply.  For some reason IE is adding an element inbetween and it is breaking your selector.

Comment: THANK YOU! That works great. I'm not sure why IE was breaking it.. and thanks for the element ending fix